# Extract number of frames without using shell-True

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg

I have the following code that extract number of frames from video:

```
filename = "test.mp4"
video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
with open(video_path, "rb") as file:
    cmd = f'ffmpeg -i {video_path} -r 10 -q:v 3 -s 1x1 -f image2 -update 1 - >/dev/null'
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, shell=True)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()

    # i.e: 'frame= 2062 fps=966 q=3.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:10:34.46 bitrate=N/A dup=1049 drop=3563 speed= 297x'
    decoded = stderr.decode('utf-8')
    frame_count_line = decoded.splitlines()[-2]
    m = FRAME_COUNT_REGEX.search(frame_count_line)
    if m:
        print(int(m.groups()[0]))
```

but because of security reasons I want to remove `shell=True` parameter.
Unfortunately after that the code above throws:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help to fix it

Comment: Quote your input url `-i "{video_path}"`. Alternately, pass a list to `Popen` with each argument as a separate item (then do not put the quotes). The latter is the preferred approach IMHO.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to open the video file in Python.

Comment: Remove the ">/dev/null" at the end of "cmd". You can instead set "Popen" argument "stdout" to "sp.DEVNULL".

Comment: @kesh quoting `-i "{video_path}"` didn't help

Comment: In Linux we can't put everything in one line. Use `proc = sp.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), `...

Comment: I think @MichaelButscher got it right (didn't think of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your command into a list e.g.

```
import subprocess
media = 'some media.mp4'
try:
    comm = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', media, '-f', 'null', '-'],
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", str(e))

try:
    with comm.stdout:
        for i in iter(comm.stdout.readline, b''):
            if i != '':
                print(i.strip())
            else:
                break
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", str(e))
```

You could also use `ffprobe` rather than `ffmpeg` because `ffprobe` allows you to select things like `-count_frames` and `-show_frames`.
Counting frames will only output the final figure, so if you need to show what's going on, you might be better with `-show_frames`.
e.g.

```
ffprobe -show_frames -count_frames -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -show_entries frame=coded_picture_number -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 -i media
```

or

```
ffprobe -count_frames -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 -i media
```

or

```
ffprobe -show_frames -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=coded_picture_number -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 -i media
```

Comment: the speed is critical in my case, I think that my version is faster

Comment: @petrush So use your version, the principle behind the code is the same. See my edit.